# How do I fix a No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet error?

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, entity

I deleted a table from a database. I then tried to update the model from database and ended up deleting and re-adding the ADO.NET entity model but I still get this error:

Models.RecDB.msl(3,4) : error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - RecAppLogs

I cant find RecAppLogs anywhere in the solution or the .edmx files. It is no where in the database server either.

Answer (score 1):

I updated from database the stored procedures and it worked. They had nothing to do with the deleted table but after hours and hours that was the thing that worked....